# Environment variable specifying preferred terminal

Tags: terminal, environment-variables

Is there a canonical way to specify a (per-user, or system wide) preferred terminal emulator, just like the `EDITOR` environment variable specifies the preferred text editor?

Comment: @kusalananda Indeed, I deleted my comment. @Hugo Can you explain what you mean by terminal emulator, are you specifically referring to the graphical terminal launched when you open a "terminal window" from your desktop environment, or controlling the type of terminal it emulates, the latter would be specific to the type of terminal used. e.g. enabling `VT102` mode in `xterm` would be different than for `xfce4-term`

Comment: I am referring to the actual graphical terminal launched, more specifically an environment variable containing the name (or path to) the executable launching it (in my case `urxvt`, or `/usr/bin/urxvt`)

Comment: It is based on your eesktop environment.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16808231/how-do-i-set-default-terminal-to-terminator

Comment: @Ipor Sircer: I am looking for a more generic way of doing it, without being aware of the actual graphical environment that will take care of the window that will be spawned (just like a program using `$EDITOR` does not know how the resulting command will actually be handled). But I guess your comment means that there is currently no canonical way.

Comment: @HugoRaguet I don't quite understand `ctrl-alt-t` style shortcut is DE specific convenience, and requires knowledge of the DE configuration to change, same with the default emulator for shell applications launched from GUI. Otherwise a user is free to start whatever terminal application they have permissions for, no? There is no shell concept of "default terminal emulator" its purely a DE feature. If there is an environment variable that controls this configuration it would be specific to the DE

Comment: @crasic who said anything about `ctrl-alt-t`? To be more clear, I am using daily a bunch of scripts in which new terminal-emulators are invoked at some point. Currently the actual command is hard-coded. For instance, I have a `term-edit.sh` containing `urxvt -e $EDITOR $1&` and I am telling my browser to use this executable to open text files by default. I expect this to work under most graphical environments, however I might use the same script on machines lacking `urxvt`. So I would like to use a generic environment variable, if it ever exists, instead of `urxvt`.